# Is there a way to replace columns in dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas, merge

*I edited the question a little based on the answers I received!

This is my first data frame. In reality, it has over 30K columns = df

| cl_id | gained_from_sup | lost_to_sup | fixed_term |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | 3 | 5 | NaN |
| 1002 | 1 | 1 | NaN |
| 1003 | 4 | 2 | 12 |
| 1004 | 1 | 3 | 6 |

This is my second dataframe which has the supplier ID - this matches the numbers in gained from Sup and lost to Sup to the corresponding supplier name = df_supp

| supplier_id | supplier_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | KFC |
| 2 | Costa |
| 3 | Nandos |
| 4 | Starbucks |
| 5 | Burger King |

After merging them using pd.merge and how’left’, left on gained from… right on supp Id..

It outputs the first df with df_supp to the end. It does match the keys correctly but is there a way to replace the iDS in df with the names from df2 since the table will not make sense when 2 Columns (gained_from and lost_from in df1 the supp_id when merged only matches the gained on.

This is my desired output:

| cl_id | gained_from_sup | lost_to_sup | fixed_term |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | Nandos | Burger King. | NaN |
| 1002 | KFC | KFC. | NaN |
| 1003 | Starbucks | Costa. | 12 |
| 1004 | KFC | Nandos. | 6 |

Or is there a better way to reformat the table to show the corresponding IDs and names for both gained_from_sup and lost_from_sup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best way to convert 2nd dataframe to dictionary and then map it.

```
cols = ['gained_from_sup', 'lost_to_sup']
lookup_name = df2.set_index('supplier_id')['supplier_name'].to_dict()
df1[cols] = df1[cols].replace(lookup_name)
```

Another method by not selecting columns

```
lookup_name = df2.set_index('supplier_id')['supplier_name'].to_dict()
df1 = df1.replace(lookup_name)
```

Comment: Thank you, I’m quite new to using cols and map compared to merge so thank you for this solution, i have so much more to learn. And if there’s an easier/best way to sort larger amounts of data (50k). Much appreciated!

Comment: I have added the another way. May be it will much easier to work upon.

Comment: This is the shortest way to handle large problems without mentioning column names. If you like this one, please accept this answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

### `DataFrame.replace`

```
df1.replace(df2.set_index('supplier_id')['supplier_name'])
```

If you want to perform replacement in only subset of columns:

```
cols = ['gained_from_sup', 'lost_to_sup']    
df1.assign(**df1[cols].replace(df2.set_index('supplier_id')['supplier_name']))
```

---

```
   cl_id gained_from_sup  lost_to_sup
0   1001          Nandos  Burger King
1   1002             KFC          KFC
2   1003       Starbucks        Costa
3   1004             KFC       Nandos
```

Comment: Hey, I used this an it worked well for the dataframe in the question I asked, however my actual dataframe has more columns and this code seemed to change the details in the other columns too . So I’ve updated the question with an extra column. Thank you

Comment: @EPlugz Please check the edit.

Comment: You can do: `df3 = df1.assign(**df1[cols].replace(df2.set_index('supplier_id')['supplier_name']))
`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `map` here, creating a dictionary of `df_supp`:

```
df["gained_from_sup"] = df["gained_from_sup"].map(df_supp.set_index("supplier_id")["supplier_name"].to_dict())
df["lost_to_sup"] = df["lost_to_sup"].map(df_supp.set_index("supplier_id")["supplier_name"].to_dict())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# setup
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'cl_id' : [1001, 1002, 1003, 1004], 'gained_from_sup': [3, 1, 4, 1], 'lost_to_sup': [5, 1, 2, np.nan], 'fixed_term': [np.nan, np.nan, 12,6]})
df_supp = pd.DataFrame({'supplier_id': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'supplier_name': ['KFC', 'Costa', 'Nandos', 'Starbucks', 'Burger King']})
# first merge
intermediate = df.merge(df_supp, left_on='gained_from_sup', right_on='supplier_id', how='left').drop(columns=['gained_from_sup', 'supplier_id'])
intermediate = intermediate.rename(columns= {'supplier_name': 'gained_from_sup'})
# second merge
final = intermediate.merge(df_supp, left_on='lost_to_sup', right_on='supplier_id', how='left').drop(columns=['lost_to_sup', 'supplier_id'])
final = final.rename(columns= {'supplier_name': 'lost_from_sup'})
# display result
final
```

Comment: Interesting. After trying this, it does exactly what I want however it only shows the data that includes both a ‘gained from’ and ‘lost from’ for example if a client has not left us = NaN. It is not shown.

Comment: Obviously, because pandas creates an inner join by default. Set how='left' in the merge options to keep those values (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)

Comment: Have edited my answer to show the code with your added 'fixed_term' column and one example of supplier with 'gained_from' but without 'lost_to'

Comment: Ah yes, my fault, I’m dealing with large piece of data so it’s quite annoying in the first place. But thank you for your solution. Very much appreciated and cool to see different versions of doing the same thing.